# How to check if the files exist on the FTP server?

Tags: windows, ms-access, ftp, windows-scripting

I have a ms-access application, now I need to check if that file had already uploaded before and then change the status of that record, is any tools or command we can use to check if the file exists?  Or even some other appliaction I can use on windows and be able to update the records in the SQL server database.

Environment:
Ms-Access 2000 + SQLserver ODBC
FTP server linux
FTP tools: Ipswitch ws_ftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Internet Data Transfer Library](http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0037.htm). It should have the necessary code you need to work with the FTP Server.